# How to get address of image file uploaded in bucket firebase nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

I am writing a blog in firebase in nodejs and expressjs.

All things are working fine in my web application, but I am unable to add images in my blog article which were uploaded to firebase hosting bucket.

Saved path of image file in bucket is : "/blog-pictures/feature-image-1.jpg"
And there are many files for each article, so I want the full relative/real address of this image file or bucket so that I can show its download url and will be able to show image properly.

I need this image/bucket address while fetching content from blog collection.

Please guide.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show the code you're working with that performs the upload, so we can see what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple.  after storageref.put() function. You get the URL using storageref.getDownloadURL() function.

Comment: But If the address of bucket is changed in future ? Main is the bucket address.

Comment: I am yet to see the bucket address change on it own especially if you've set your rules correctly, so the image URL will remain the same. I use it for an ecommence site in production and so far no image URLs have been changed unless explicitly changed.

Comment: Hello Jjhok, can you send me some examples, please.

Comment: Its better explained here in the documentation explained and demonstrated with code.hope that helps https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files